# Swing GUI: JList with jtextFields on the rows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jlist

My problem is:

I have a button that will add components to a JList when it is clicked. Each row of the list is composed by two jtextFields. The first is the ID of the row. Every time I press the "Add button", a new row appears, the ID is incremented, and the person who is using the application will write whatever he want on the second jTextField (forward the ID field).

Then it will have a scroll pane for when there are more than 4 rows.
And I want a Remove Button too. To be possible to remove some rows.

Can you help me with this? I don't know how to create a list like this...

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that. `JList` is not a container, its a component, so it can't hold components. Why do you (think you) need a JList? Why not just do this with a `JPanel`?

Comment: I really don't know how to start. Ok, that's logic. But I have to create a list anyway right? To add the fields every time the button is pressed. There is also a Remove button, to be possible to remove some rows.

Comment: Better to use a JTable with two columns, the first not been editable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `JTable` with two columns.  This will allow you to establish two columns, one for the ID and one for the value.  This will allow you make the second column editable.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTable04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable04();
    }

    private int id = 0;

    public TestTable04() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final RecordTableModel model = new RecordTableModel();
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JButton add = new JButton("Add");
                add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.add(new Record(++id));
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class Record {

        private int id;
        private String value;

        public Record(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    public class RecordTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Record> lstRecords;

        public RecordTableModel() {
            lstRecords = new ArrayList<>(24);
        }

        public void add(Record record) {
            lstRecords.add(record);
            fireTableRowsInserted(lstRecords.size() - 1, lstRecords.size() - 1);
        }

        public void remove(Record record) {
            if (lstRecords.contains(record)) {
                int index = lstRecords.indexOf(record);
                remove(index);
            }
        }

        public void remove(int index) {
            lstRecords.remove(index);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return lstRecords.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            Class clazz = String.class;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    clazz = Integer.class;
                    break;
            }
            return clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            String name = null;
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    name = "ID";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = "Value";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Record record = lstRecords.get(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = record.getID();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = record.getValue();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Record record = lstRecords.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                    record.setValue(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Wow, very nice! Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a icon in a table cell? In a third column.

Comment: Sure, start by checking [How to use renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom ListCellRenderer and use JList's setRenderer method to assign it. Override the getListCellRenderer() method of ListCellRenderer to return a JPanel containing two components, a JLabel for the id, and a JTextfield for the user input. You may need to keep a reference to the JTextField elsewhere so that you can retrieve the user input.

To implement the add and remove methods, I would recommend backing the JList with a ListModel. Add and remove to the ListModel will also update the JList UI.